# Swift KYDrawerController height of drawer is not full

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Using this library for sidemenu: https://github.com/ykyouhei/KYDrawerController

And I am getting this, but height is not full:

[image]

This is my setup:

[image]

On initial VC:

```
Class: KYDrawerController
Module: KYDrawerController
```

Attributes

```
mainSegueIdentifier: main
drawerSegueIdentifier: drawer
```

Everithing works but this height.
What can be problem here?

Comment: backgroundColor could be clearColor

Comment: Problem is height here, not background..